# Canvas, calculating start point 20% in line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing, line

http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/TUyJb/3/

I recently asked a question to calculate the endpoint of a line in canvas based on percentage: [Canvas, drawing a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135389/canvas-drawing-a-line-segment)

Now, I am stuck with how to calculate X percentage in the line from startpoint to be used as actual startpoint.

In the fiddle above, I have tried to mirror endpoints:

```
growth = 0.2;

// calculate line endpoint
current.x = start.x + (target.x - start.x) * growth;
current.y = start.y + (target.y - start.y) * growth;

// calculate line startpoint
scurrent.x = start.x + (start.x - target.x) * growth;
scurrent.y = start.y + (start.y - target.y) * growth;
```

But that does not seem to do what I want it to do.

My real goal is to make a function, that would draw a line:

- in boundaries of point x, to point y
- with length of n
- and starting at position z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are stated as the endpoint is actually your "startpoint":

```
// calculate line "endpoint"
current.x = start.x + (target.x - start.x) * growth;
current.y = start.y + (target.y - start.y) * growth;
```

here is a function that returns a waypoint:

```
// start and end are points with .x and .y
// q is a number between 0.0 and 1.0
var waypoint = function (start, end, q) {

    return {
        x: start.x + (end.x - start.x) * q,
        y: start.y + (end.y - start.y) * q
    };
}
```

now you can calculate waypoint wherever you want:

```
var start = {x: 10, y: 20},
    end = {x: 120, y: 70},

    a = waypoint(start, end, 0.2),
    b = waypoint(start, end, 0.8);
```

`a` and `b` will be point 20% in from either end of the original line.